# Why saved image size is different by python selenium

Tags: python, image, selenium, size

I used two way to save image with python selenium, the image file size is different about 10 times, how can I let size in way2 as the same as way1?

Way1:

```
imgData = urllib.request.urlopen(urlServer).read()
output = open(pathLocal, 'wb')
output.write(imgData)
output.close()
```

Way2:

```
browser.get(urlServer)
browser.save_screenshot(pathLocal)
```

Then I found way2 can be used for two urls, but way1 can only be used for 2nd url, does any one tell me why?

```
1. http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg
2. https://secure-api.userlocal.jp/ipcamera/posts/files/16/41/502241_2017022116205643436_830aaf54751.jpg.
```

Comment: `save_screenshot` is like taking a screenshot of the contents of the browser. Whereas in "Way1" you are downloading the actual image from that request.

Comment: But that page is just a image like this http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg or https://secure-api.userlocal.jp/ipcamera/posts/files/16/41/502241_2017022116205643436_830aaf54751.jpg.

Comment: Those link simple displays the image onto the browser. If the headers for that response contained `Content-Disposition: attachment` then it would've downloaded the image.

Comment: For a cheap workaround, you can try something link [this](http://www.testingexcellence.com/how-to-download-and-save-images-with-selenium-rc/). But "Way1" is still the correct approach.

Comment: Can I let way1 has the same size as way2?

Comment: @JRodDynamite Can you help me to solve this problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381234/python-selenium-to-show-pull-down-list-and-select-it, the image is shown on landscape at first, when I move mouse to link on left top, a pull down menu shown, after I select change orientation, dialog show and image show in portrait after clicked radio button, can you help me?